# What is the difference between CXFRs conponent and HTTP component

Tags: web-services, http, apache-camel, endpoint, cxfrs

is it true to say that cxfrs component is used for calling RESTful web service inside ESB and HTTP component is used for remote webservice ?
What is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

The CFXRS component can be found here http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html . As you can read the main purpose is *for connecting to JAX-RS 1.1 and 2.0 services hosted in CXF*.

The Camel-HTTP can both receive and call standard HTTP services.

Whether the services reside inside camel or remote does not really matter.